# Toggle text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a easier way to toggle 2 or more text visibility? When I've used a `.toggle()` method, the text jumps up and down, because they are toggled at the same time. With `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` it's working correctly, but the code is messy.

```js
var triggerTitle = function() {
  var hasClassHide = $(".hero-title.1").hasClass("hide");

  if (hasClassHide) {
    $(".hero-title.1").removeClass("hide");
    $(".hero-title.1").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".hero-title.2").addClass("hide");
    $(".hero-title.2").fadeOut(1000);
    $(".hero-title.2").css("display", "none");
  } else {
    $(".hero-title.2").removeClass("hide");
    $(".hero-title.2").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".hero-title.1").addClass("hide");
    $(".hero-title.1").fadeOut(1000);
    $(".hero-title.1").css("display", "none");
  }
};

setInterval(triggerTitle, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="hero-title 1">WEB DEVELOPER</h1>
<h1 class="hero-title 2 hide" style="display: none;">WEB DESIGNER</h1>
```

Comment: If you put the code into a snippet, it can be tried out directly on this page :)

Comment: I don't understand what you want, but for `fadeIn` and `fadeout` you don't need set also `css("display", "none")`.

Comment: try like this 
`if (hasClassHide) {
        $(".hero-title.1").removeClass("hide");
        $(".hero-title.2").fadeOut(1000);
        $(".hero-title.1").fadeIn(1000);
        $(".hero-title.2").addClass("hide");
    } else {
        $(".hero-title.2").removeClass("hide");
        $(".hero-title.1").fadeOut(1000);
        $(".hero-title.2").fadeIn(1000);
        $(".hero-title.1").addClass("hide");
    }`

Comment: @A.J. this should be an answer. Working fine, just needs a bit of css styling.

Comment: @ByteHamster don't forget mark my answer as useful ;)

Comment: @A.J. If you post this as an answer instead of a comment, you get reputation for upvotes. Moreover, there is syntax highlighting etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach:

```js
$('h1').hide();

var titles = ['web developer', 'web designer'];
var index = -1;
var triggerTitle = function() {
  $('h1').fadeOut();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('h1').text(titles[index].toUpperCase());
    $('h1').fadeIn();
  }, 1000);
  index = (index < titles.length - 1) ? index + 1 : 0;
  console.log(index);
};

setInterval(triggerTitle, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1></h1>
```

This way you store your messages into a single array and you can add as many titles as you want. And you only have a single `<h1>` tag in your HTML. The code becomes much more cleaner.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Andrey, but now on page load the title is empty. Is there a way to fix that as well?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment of `@A.J.`, I have added some CSS. Looks really nice now.

```js
var triggerTitle = function() {
  var hasClassHide = $(".hero-title.1").hasClass("hide");

  if (hasClassHide) { 
    $(".hero-title.1").removeClass("hide"); 
    $(".hero-title.2").fadeOut(1000); 
    $(".hero-title.1").fadeIn(1000); 
    $(".hero-title.2").addClass("hide"); 
  } else { 
    $(".hero-title.2").removeClass("hide"); 
    $(".hero-title.1").fadeOut(1000); 
    $(".hero-title.2").fadeIn(1000); 
    $(".hero-title.1").addClass("hide"); }
};

setInterval(triggerTitle, 3000);
```

```css
h1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="hero-title 1">WEB DEVELOPER</h1>
<h1 class="hero-title 2 hide" style="display: none;">WEB DESIGNER</h1>
```